# למנצח on tisha b’av

Tags: tisha-bav

Between Ashrei and Uva L’tzion we say Lamnatzeach. It’s apparently a somber psalm referring to the period before the Beis Hamikdosh was rebuilt, and since it’s sad in nature we don’t say it on festive days such as Rosh Chodesh, Purim, Chanukah etc. but we also don’t say it on Tisha bav, one of the saddest days in our calendar…why?

Sorta related but doesn’t really give an answer: [Why is Tishah B’Av considered a holiday?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94102/why-is-tishah-b-av-considered-a-holiday)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.552.14?lang=bi

Comment: @Chatzkel he says that we don’t say it because we have faith in Hashem that he will eventually turn Tisha B’av into a festive holiday…but then why don’t we also omit למנצח and the such on tzom gedalia, shiva assar b’tammuz, and asarah b’tevet?

Comment: I don’t have a source but I always understood that Tisha Bav we express the aveilus in a most dramatic way, so as to not be misunderstood as hopelessness, we also celebrate the future as well. The other fasts we don’t eat but we sit on chairs, have a relatively normal day, so we don’t have to offset it with showing hope for the future.

Comment: Maybe it's to minimize Talmud Torah. This section is essentially just some post prayer study.

Comment: @Chatzkel it’s funny I actually just heard a class today that answered my question. The rabbi put it like this- his prelude was asking how the Temple could’ve burned if it was made of stone mostly and not wood, and he answered that as it says in Eicha, Gashem poured his wrath into the bricks of the Temple. So, rather than turning his anger on the Jewish people and completely eliminating us, Hashem spared us and took his anger out on His house instead. So because we got saved when we could’ve been destroyed, we sorta also celebrate and call Tisha Bav a holiday

Comment: 1. an avel who lost a close relative also skips this 2. Tisha b'av that the day will be a yontiff in the times of moshiach